# Installing mysql - Fedora20 - Where is the installation directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, fedora, mysql

I am trying to install mysql on to a Fedora 20 box. I am using the below guide which states the following;

> First, MySQL was replaced by MariaDB since Fedora 19
>   (http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ReplaceMySQLwithMariaDB).
>
> To install MariaDB Server you have to execute the following command:
>
> yum install mariadb mariadb-server To start MariaDB on Fedora 20,
>   execute the following command:
>
> systemctl start mariadb.service To autostart MariaDB on Fedora 20,
>   execute the following command:
>
> systemctl enable mariadb.service After you started MariaDB (do this
>   only once), execute the following command:
>
> /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation This command will ask you some
>   inputs to set root password, remove anonymous users, disallow root
>   login remotely, remove test database and reload privilege tables.

I have completed step one with no issues :) So the packages were installed with no issue and i even received the following message - `Complete!` The second step however is driving me nuts. I get the following error message

> [root@secondstory1d etc]# systemctl enable mariadb.service Failed to
>   issue method call: No such file or directory

I assume this is because I am not in the correct installation directory - however - I m unsure how to find where that is

Please can someone advise where I might need to look.

Thanks

Comment: What command did you run in step 2?

Comment: i tired both systemctl start mariadb.service and systemctl enable mariadb.service

Comment: i found mysql in /usr/bin which i am able to start and stop, but there is no my.cnf to edit in here so i am not sure if this is the right installation directory either

Comment: Maybe a dont understand youre question good enough, but it seems that the database is already setted-up after the mysql_secure invocation